# Passing argument on action in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have three toggle buttons in my "hbs" file.
And I have "options" array in the controller related to this template.
I want to update "options" whenever user selected/deselected any of buttons.
For example, if button 1 selected and other not - "options" must be [1].
If second and third buttons selected and first not - "options" must be [2, 3].

And I tried to make this through actions with parameters:

```
<button {{action 'toggleOption' name aria-pressed}}
id="first-button" name="1" type="button" class="btn 
option-toggle-button" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false"
autocomplete="off">First button</button>
```

Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    options: [],
    actions: {
        toggleOption(id, selected) {
            var options = this.get("options");

            if (selected) {
                if (options.contains(id))
                    options.push(id);
            } else {
                var index = options.indexOf(id);
                if (index >= 0)
                    options.splice(index, 1);
            }

            this.set("options", options);
        }
    }
});
```

But "toggleOption" was calling with "undefined" params so I assume that I on a wrong way.

Question: how can I implement needed logic? Maybe I need a completely different approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<button {{action 'toggleOption' "1"}} id="first-button" name="1" type="button" class="btn option-toggle-button" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false"autocomplete="off">First button</button>

<button {{action 'toggleOption' "2"}} id="first-button" name="1" type="button" class="btn option-toggle-button" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false"autocomplete="off">Second button</button>
```

where `"1" and "2"` are the values passed to the controller action.
Then in the `toggleOption` action you can do your logic to add/remove value into `options` array

```
actions: {
    toggleOption(value) {
        // ...your logic here...
    }
}
```

Comment: And just ignore real state of button? Yeah... Maybe you right, simplest solution = best solution. I'm just afraid that "options" may get out of sync with buttons for some reasons. So I hope that maybe Ember has more elegant solution.